# jquery popup not correct work in php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I am using this jquery popup

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 // Here we will write a function when link click under class popup                   
$('a.popup').click(function() {


 // Here we will describe a variable popupid which gets the
// rel attribute from the clicked link                            
var popupid = $(this).attr('rel');


// Now we need to popup the marked which belongs to the rel attribute
// Suppose the rel attribute of click link is popuprel then here in below code
// #popuprel will fadein
$('#' + popupid).fadeIn();


  // append div with id fade into the bottom of body tag
 // and we allready styled it in our step 2 : CSS
  $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
  $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();


  // Now here we need to have our popup box in center of 
  // webpage when its fadein. so we add 10px to height and width 
   var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
  var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;


  // Then using .css function style our popup box for center allignment
   $('#' + popupid).css({
 'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
  'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
   });
    });


   // Now define one more function which is used to fadeout the 
  // fade layer and popup window as soon as we click on fade layer
   $('#fade').click(function() {


   // Add markup ids of all custom popup box here                           
   $('#fade , #popuprel , #popuprel2 , #popuprel3').fadeOut()
    return false;
     });
    });
```

and it's my php and html code in my foreach loop:

```
             <?php foreach($items as $item){ ?>
             <a rel="popuprel" class="popup">click hier</a>
             <div class="popupbox" id="popuprel">
            <div id="intabdiv">
               <?php echo $item->description; ?>
              </div>
             </div>
            <div id="fade"></div>
           <?php } ?>
```

now when click and show popup only echo one item description for all items but I want echo each item description for each item.

Comment: your are creating divs with same id  inside foreach loop, id should be unique.( append item.id with id value.)

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript:

```
<script>

function show_description(id)
{
    $('desc').fadeOut();
    $('#description_' + id).fadeIn();
}

</script>
```

The PHP/HTML:

```
         <?php foreach($items as $item){ ?>
         <a rel="popuprel" onclick="show_description(<?=$this->id; ?>);">click hier</a>
         <div class="popupbox" id="popuprel">
        <div class="desc" id="description_<?=$this->id;?>">
           <?php echo $item->description; ?>
          </div>
         </div>
        <div id="fade"></div>
       <?php } ?>
```

I assume you can fetch the ID of your item with "$this->id", that's why I used it in the code.

Comment: thank you dear viktor i change to it: $('.description').fadeIn(); but my popup not work

Comment: What happens when you click it?

Comment: Ok, but I'm a little confused. When you click the "click hier" button, do you want ALL descriptions to show or just the description corresponding to that entry?

Comment: i have a many button "click hier" because i am using foraech loop and i have more item now I want when click each button echo this row description

Answer (score 0):

I found how can do it
i replace all **popuprel** with this code:

```
$item->id
```

it's now work